# A Hyperlink Formula field behaviour in lightning experience

Tags: visualforce, lightning, hyperlink

A Hyperlink Formula field, that's supposed to navigate to a Visualforce page, opens in one/one.app mode for few users and visualforce mode for others. This behaviour happens only in lightning. What could be the reason for this ?   I have checked for Salesforce1 user field ( if that's required ) on all users, it's false.

Here is the field value :

```
    IF (OR(---condition---),IF(OR($User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme4d', $User.UIThemeDisplayed == 'Theme4t'), HYPERLINK("/apex/---VFPage1--->?id="&Id,
 IMAGE("/resource/test", "Test"), "_self"), HYPERLINK("/apex/---VF_Page2---?id="&Id, IMAGE("/resource/test", "Test"), "_self")), NULL)
```

Comment: Can you add the hyperlink in the question as well?

Comment: added it. @sanketkumar